# Cassandra-check whether column name exists in column family

Tags: cassandra, hector

Am using hector java client for cassandra. Using Java how can i check whether particular column Name in column family exists or not?

Comment: Column name may exist for a specific row with a specific key, not for the whole CF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have to attempt to retrieve the column. If this succeeds, then the column exists. If not, then it doesn't.

From the [user guide](https://github.com/rantav/hector/wiki/User-Guide):

```
ColumnQuery<String, String, String> columnQuery =
    HFactory.createStringColumnQuery(keyspace);
columnQuery.setColumnFamily("Standard1").setKey("jsmith").setName("first");
QueryResult<HColumn<String, String>> result = columnQuery.execute();
```

If your column values are very large, and you don't want to retrieve them like this, then one trick is to store a small 'companion' column that indicates the presence of the large column.